# Express $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \, dx$ as a series of constants $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

**Exercise** Express $\int_0^1 x^{-x} \, dx$ as a series of constants $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$

---

This problem isn't so straightforward, I don't believe. But I can get myself started.

Consider first that $x^{-x} = e^{\ln x^{-x}} = e^{-x\ln x}$

We then consider the power series for $e^u = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{u^n}{n!}$. We let $u= -x \ln (x)$ and integrate.

Integrating both sides, we have

$$\int_0^1 e^{-x \ln x} \, dx = \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n!} \int_0^1 (-x \ln x)^n \, dx$$

From here, the integrals I'm obtaining end up being special gamma integrals which don't make much sense to me. Am I headed in the right direction? Can anyone give me a hint to make this integration more efficient and (hopefully) more compact? Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream

Comment: @MartinR I believe so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us factor out that pesky $(-1)^n$ from that integral and consider
$$\int_0^1 e^{-x\ln(x)}dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{n!}I_n$$
where
$$I_n = \int_0^1 x^n\ln(x)^n dx$$
let us do a change of variables $u = -\ln(x)$ and so $dx = -e^{-u}du$ and $u(0) = \infty$ and $u(1) = 0$. Then we have (after factoring the negative signs)
$$I_n = (-1)^n \int_0^\infty e^{-(n+1)u} u^n du $$
Now let $t = (n+1)u$, $du = \frac{1}{n+1}dt$
$$I_n = (-1)^n \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+1)^{n+1}}e^{-t}t^n dt$$
Thus finally, $I_n = \frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)^{n+1}} \Gamma(n+1)$. This was obtained from the definition of $\Gamma$ which is given as
$$\Gamma(z) = \int_0^\infty x^{z-1}e^{-x}dx$$

The only fact about $\Gamma$ you really need to know is that it generalizes factorials, and so $\Gamma(n+1) = n!$
Can you take it from here?